# Is this use of optocoupler wrong?

Tags: transistors, bjt, opto-isolator

[image]

This is nearly not exactly how the circuit looks like, but I have a feeling that this circuit could cause problems while working. My feeling is that initially as Q1 would be in ON position, the collector voltage at the optocoupler would be 0.6V and hence to turn ON the transistor of the optocoupler, the base voltage would have to be more than 1.0V. The CTR is 470% as "If" is 5mA.

I feel the circuit is wrong. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: What do you mean by "to turn ON the transistor of the optocoupler, the base voltage would have to be more than 1.0V"? That transistor is turned on by the light from the LED.

Comment: I'm at the assumption that as Q1 is ON.... The Voltage at the base of Q1 would be .7V hence isn't it necessary for a higher voltage at the base of the optocouppler...even though I know it's an LED powering it

Comment: Could you try again, I don't understand that. And for your original question: what exactly don't you understand about the circuit?

Comment: The Thing is this circuit fails randomly... And I don't know why....My thinking was for this to fail is that light from the diode is not enough saturate the optocoupler IC....(not sure). The failure is that the switch is closed but Q1 is ON... happens randomly...

Comment: Do you really have 110Vdc supplying the LED in your optocoupler? Where does this come from?

Comment: What is the part number of your opto-coupler?

Comment: PC817x Series OptoCoupler

Comment: Is the input really a 110V battery, or AC? If it is AC, you're destroying the LED by applying 100V in reverse across it, while it can only take <6V.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a datasheet link or a part number for the opto, but I can make some educated guesses. First, the 470% CTR is a suspiciously high number as a guaranteed minimum at 5mA LED current for a **phototransistor output** isolator. If it's actually a Darlington output, then you'll need to modify the circuit to get to work reliably as the saturation voltage will be too high.

Suppose it's something like the excellent [FOD817D](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FO/FOD814A.pdf) (the D is important) which has a CTR range of 300-600 with 5mA in. That is specified with Vce of 5.0V and you require less than 0.5V for it to work reliably. The effective CTR will be much lower. Figure 3 shows you that you can **typically** expect it to handle 2.5mA at the output (good design will add a substantial amount of margin for aging, temperature and unit-to-unit variations, so maybe 0.8mA is safe). You are at 250uA, so the particular part I mention should be more than okay.

Suppose you are using a Darlington type or an optoisolator that is not as high performance?

Well, you need to add some voltage drop between the optoisolator collector and the transistor base. Since you have plenty of voltage (12V supply) and the optos are specified at 5V, you could insert a 5.1V zener diode between the opto as so..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faAien.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Vce of the opto is about 5.6V at the threshold, and the zener diode I suggested has a 5.1V breakdown at 50uA (the circuit switches at about 60uA) so all the parts are well specified. Nominal base current is similar to your circuit, about 180uA. You'd really like to see more like 2-4mA maximum for the transistor to be well saturated, so maybe you can increase the 1K to about 3.6 to 5.2K. If you really need the 1K then increase the base current using the method I illustrated above, use a MOSFET or darlington or a really high performance BJT.

TL;DR: There are a couple of things that look marginal in this circuit, the real optoisolator drop at saturation and the base current of the output transistor. They both should be fixed.

Comment: I tried the simulation for the circit I provided...yet it shows no problems.... the 1k is just a reference.... it is used to stop an oscillator....The OptoCoupler is a PC817x Series....The parts I missed out in the circuit was the 110V supply would be connected to two coils Which would energize  alternately and the coils do have flyback diodes...with the simulation I did, I found that only when the forward diode current becomes less than 1mA it fails.... but 1mA is like very unlikely at all....And the failure occurs randomly, it might take days to appear....

Answer (score 0):

If you are having failures of the LED in the opto-isolator, try adding a diode in series with R4.  Something like 1n4005 will do nicely.

I'm thinking that there is the possibility of significant reverse voltage across the LED - this can damage or destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

The optocoupler is a current source/sink. with a CTR of 470% (pretty high) it will try to draw 23 mA, but R2 will only allow maximum 250 uA. When the switch is closed the optocoupler will therefore effectively pull Q1's base to ground, switching it off.
The circuit should work correctly.